# Facebook Connect Plugin Cordova 3.4 how to get friends list

Tags: android, ios, facebook, cordova

I have an issue when trying to get friends list. 
I use facebookConnectPlugin https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin and cordova 3.4
It worked for with cordova 3.1 and old version of the plugin (for cordova 3.1).
Then I've updated cordova to 3.4 and also have updated FB connect plugin.

In the previous version I used:

```
FB.api('/me/friends', {fields: 'id, name, picture'}, onFriends);
```

Currently I tried the following code:

```
facebookConnectPlugin.api('/me/friends', {fields: 'id, name, picture'}, onFriends);
```

Currently it opens safari and show an error:

**"Invalid Scope: fields"**

I have mentioned that facebookConnectPlugin.api method was changed and works only for iOS.

Any thoughts how I can get friends list of current user?

Comment: you got that error because second argument should be success_callback function. like facebookConnectPlugin.api('/me/friends', onSuccess, onError); btw, did you figured out that? Facebook did not respond to me when I call '/me/friends'

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's supposed to work with `facebookConnectPlugin.api(...` but they are facing some stability issues. You can follow up here:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin/issues/468

Anyway, I downloaded the version from the dev branch and it works as expected.